# Hot deployment in jboss 7.1.1 final not working in eclipse on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss7.x

when i make a change in any of my jsp/html pages and reload jsp/html page then modified content is not loading. What should i do for this problem ? It worked proper in jboss 7.1.0 but does not work in jboss 7.1.1 Final.
 I modified standalone.xml of jboss7.1.1 to:
 auto-deploy-exploded="true" 
and add configuration :

```
<jsp-configuration development="true"/>
```

Both changes not working. But in auto-deploy-exploded="true" it restarts jboss when i change any file. This is not that i want.
Is there any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: can you please add subsystem tag content of standalone.xml?

Comment: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
            </configuration> </<subsystem> 
This is added by me but not working.